# Linq Group result to an Object

Tags: c#, linq

**Overview**

When I have a class as

```
public class RequestEntry
{
    public int RequestId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string ApproverUserId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string ApproverUserName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public DateTime RequestedDate
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

and it includes in a List as:

```
List<RequestEntry> RequestEntries = new List<RequestEntry>()
{
    new RequestEntry{RequestId = 1, RequestedDate = new DateTime(2018,06,01), ApproverUserId = "STEVES", ApproverUserName = "Steve Smith"}, 
    new RequestEntry{RequestId = 1, RequestedDate = new DateTime(2018,06,01), ApproverUserId = "GRAHAMS", ApproverUserName = "Graham Smith" }, 
    new RequestEntry{RequestId = 2, RequestedDate = new DateTime(2018,06,02), ApproverUserId = "STEVES", ApproverUserName = "Steve Smith"}, 
    new RequestEntry{RequestId = 3, RequestedDate = new DateTime(2018,06,03), ApproverUserId = "ROBINS", ApproverUserName = "Robin Smith"}, 
    new RequestEntry{RequestId = 3, RequestedDate = new DateTime(2018,06,03), ApproverUserId = "CHRISS", ApproverUserName = "Chris Smith"}, 
    new RequestEntry{RequestId = 3, RequestedDate = new DateTime(2018,06,03), ApproverUserId = "LIAMS", ApproverUserName = "Liam Smith"} 
};
```

**Objective**

My Expected Result is to be in such way:

```
public class RequestWithApprover
{
    public int RequestId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public DateTime RequestedDate
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public List<string> ApproverUserIds
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public List<RequestApprover> RequestApprovers
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Where `RequestApprover` is defined as

```
public class RequestApprover
{
    public string ApproverUserId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string ApproverUserName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

**Workings**

After following some earlier scenarios in [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325278/group-by-in-linq/47580961#47580961), I was able to write to the extent of getting a List as defined in

```
var results = (
            from r in RequestEntries
            group r by new
            {
                r.RequestId, r.RequestedDate
            }
            into g
            select new RequestWithApprover()
            {
                RequestId = g.Key.RequestId, 
                RequestedDate = g.Key.RequestedDate, 
                ApproverUserIds = g.Select(c => c.ApproverUserId).ToList() 
                //----> Here I am able to get a List<string> but need to be in List<RequestWithApprover>
            }).ToList();
```

How Can I get the result to `List<RequestWithApprover>`?

My [DotNetFiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325278/group-by-in-linq/47580961#47580961)

Comment: Something like RequestApprovers= g.Select(c => new RequestApprover{ApproverUserId = c.ApproverUserId, ApproverUserName = c.ApproverUserName).ToList()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To achieve this goal you can you Select method with creation required object in it.
I assume this should work for you:

```
var results = (
        from r in RequestEntries
        group r by new
        {
            r.RequestId, r.RequestedDate
        }
        into g
        select new RequestWithApprover()
        {
            RequestId = g.Key.RequestId, 
            RequestedDate = g.Key.RequestedDate, 
            ApproverUserIds = g.Select(c => c.ApproverUserId).ToList() 
            RequestApprovers = g.Select(c => new RequestApprover(){ApproverUserName = c.ApproverUserName, ApproverUserId = c.ApproverUserId}).ToList()
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: Excellent! Please note there is a small correction to be made: `RequestWithApprover.RequestApprovers` accepts `List<RequestApprover>` and not `List<RequestWithApprover>` :)